# How to stop the execution of an asynchronous processing by an external command

Tags: javascript, promise

I hope this code will speak for itself
the first button launches the asynchronous command (here a setTimeout for the example) the second button allows to stop its execution during the journey.

Except that in my code it does not go as I imagined, and I admit, I still find it hard to be comfortable with the promises ....

**For the moment I  do not understand why the setTimeout has no effect ?**

What did I (still) miss?

```js
(function(messageBox)
  {
  const texBox = document.getElementById('message-box')
    ;
  messageBox.txt = txt => texBox.textContent = txt 
  messageBox.add = txt => texBox.textContent += '\n'+txt
  }
(window.messageBox=window.messageBox || {}));

function timer()
{
  let status = 'none'  // inUse 
    , obj    = document.createElement('b')
    , ref    = null
    , msTime = 0
    ;
  const sleep  =_=> new Promise(res => ref=setTimeout(res, ms))
    ,   cancel =_=> new Promise(res => {
          obj.onclick =_=> {
            if (status==='inUse') {
              clearTimeout(ref)
              res()
        } } })
  async function start( ms ) {
    if (status==='none') {
      msTime = ms 
      status = 'inUse'
      await Promise.race([sleep,cancel])
      status = 'none'
    }
  }        
  function stop() { if (status==='inUse') obj.click() }

  return( { start, stop} )
}

const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start')
  ,   btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort')
  ,   OnDelay = timer()
  ;
btStart.onclick=_=>
  {
  messageBox.txt('Start waitting 5 seconds...')
  OnDelay.start(5000)
  messageBox.add('next things to do...')
  }
btAbort.onclick=_=>
  {
  OnDelay.stop()
  messageBox.add('...abort !')
  }
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightskyblue;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>
<pre id="message-box">message...</pre>
```

the idea is : 2 options
a) click on the button `wait 5s` => messageBox will immediately display `Start waiting 5 seconds...`
 and **5 seconds later**, the program will add `finish wait:)`
  messageBox =

> Start waiting 5 seconds...
>   next things to do...

(it does not work as I hope )

b) click on the button `wait 5s` => messageBox = `Start waiting 5 seconds...` (same as =a= at this time )

then click **before** the end of the 5 seconds on the button `abort` 
  => messageBox =

> Start waiting 5 seconds...
>   ... abort!
>   next things to do...

**before the 5 seconds have elapsed**
 (it also does not work  as I hope )

Comment: No, native ES6 promise is not cancelable, you have to implement your own cancel logic or use some libraries support cancelable promise, for example bluebird

Comment: @MarkoCen I can see that, but for the moment I just want to make my code example functional

Comment: @MisterJojo so do you expect after clicking on the "wait 5s" button, it will wait for 5 seconds before the message "finish waitting :)" is printed?  You not only have promises, but also async function... to add to the picture

Comment: @MisterJojo so what does the whole program aim to do? Just to have the "wait 5s" button and it will wait 5s and print out something, and then the "abort" button to abort such an action? (obviously if pressed too late, then won't have any effect)

Comment: @MisterJojo it would elaborate the purpose and explanation of the code then it would be nice us to give more specific answer

Comment: @MisterJojo rather than go with a more complex approach I have posted answer with a simple approach, hope it will help to resolve your issue and understand the internal process behind the scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overthinking the problem.

All you need is *one* Promise and its usual `.then`, `.reject`, and `.finally()`. No `.race` is needed.

Also, you can also wrap all these operations into a class as a cleaner, reusable approach:

```js
const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start')
  ,   btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort')
  ;
  btAbort.disabled = true
  ;
const messageBox = document.getElementById('message-box')
  ;
  messageBox.txt = txt => messageBox.textContent = txt;
  messageBox.add = txt => messageBox.textContent += '\n' + txt;

class Countdown {
  constructor(onStart, onEnd, onAbort)
    {
    this.timeout       = null;
    this.handleCatch   = onAbort;
    this.handleFinally = onEnd;
    this.starter       = (res, rej) => {
                            onStart();
                            this.timeout = setTimeout(res, 5000);
                            // Pass the `reject` function to a property to be used later
                            this.aborter = rej;
                          };
    }
  async start()
    {
    try 
      {
      // Only one `Promise` is needed.
      this.main = await new Promise(this.starter);
      } 
    catch(e)  /* This will run on abort */
      {
      // Stop the timeout
      clearTimeout(this.timeout);
      // Reset the property to make sure `abort` can only be run once for each valid timeout.
      this.aborter = null;
      this.handleCatch();
      } 
    finally /* This will run after everything ends */
      {
      this.handleFinally();
      } 
    }
  abort()
    {
    if (typeof this.aborter === 'function')
      {
      // Use the `reject` that is passed to this property earlier.
      this.aborter();    
      }
    }
  }

const countdown = new Countdown(
      /* onStart  */ ()=> {
                          btAbort.disabled = false
                          messageBox.txt('Start waiting 5 seconds...')
                          },
      /* onEnd    */ ()=> {
                          btAbort.disabled = true
                          messageBox.add('next things to do...')
                          },
      /* onAbort  */ ()=> messageBox.add('...abort!')
  )

btStart.addEventListener('click', countdown.start.bind(countdown));
btAbort.addEventListener('click', countdown.abort.bind(countdown));
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin : 1em;
  border : 1px solid lightskyblue;
  padding: .3em;
  width  : 22em;
  height : 5em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>

<pre id="message-box">message...</pre>
```

This way, not only your code is clean, you can reuse the countdown anywhere in your code.

All you need to do is tell the instance what to do `onStart`, `onEnd`, and `onAbort`.

*[edit (PO)]*
*Adding some improvements :

 - disable / enable abort button

 - changing message from `finish waiting :)` to `next things to do...` which is more clear to understand this finality

+ changing style to Whitesmiths style, because I find it clearer to analyze and understand the code.*

Comment: It's a hell of a piece of code! (I learned a lot).
I continued to tinker with my slightly crazy code (small improvements), and your approach is much better, too bad you do not practice the Whitesmiths style (I did not dare to change it)

Comment: @MisterJojo glad it helped. About the code style, you can just edit it to suit your style. It won't break anything (theoretically).

Comment: Thank you for the permission, I hope that it will not seem too horrible to you ... Otherwise, your code also made me understand one of the problems of mine, I create promises which can never end (you cause a reject to finish the promise)

Comment: I have trouble understanding this line: `if (typeof this.aborter==='function')` would you have a reference or an explanation for this?

Comment: @MisterJojo that line is just to check whether `this.aborter` is a function. We should call `this.aborter()` only when it is a function. Otherwise, it will throw an exception. This is needed because we also have a line `this.aborter = null` when we are aborting the countdown.

Answer (score 1):

### Using an async function:

```js
(function(messageBox) {
    const texBox = document.getElementById('message-box');
    messageBox.txt = txt => texBox.textContent = txt
    messageBox.add = txt => texBox.textContent += '\n' + txt
  }
  (window.messageBox = window.messageBox || {}));

function timer() {
  let timerID, rejectPromise;

  function start(nMS) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      timerID = setTimeout(_ => {
        timerID = undefined;
        resolve();
      }, nMS);
      rejectPromise = reject;
    });
  }

  function stop() {
    timerID && clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = undefined;
    rejectPromise();
  }

  return ({
    start,
    stop
  })
}

const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start'),
  btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort'),
  OnDelay = timer();
  
btStart.onclick = async _ => {
  messageBox.txt('Start waitting 5 seconds...')
  try {
    await OnDelay.start(5000);
  } catch (_) {}
  messageBox.add('finish waitting :)')
}

btAbort.onclick = _ => {
  OnDelay.stop()
  messageBox.add('...abort !')
}
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightskyblue;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>
<pre id="message-box">message...</pre>
```

Note: to actually have something waiting for 5 seconds and ***then*** do something, you need to

1. have a promise `p`, which is resolved 5 seconds later by `setTimeout`, and another line to say `p.then(function() { doSomething() })`
2. or, use async function, and `await` for such a promise as in (1) above.

Since you want the same action to be done even if the promise is rejected, so I added a `try... catch` to the `await`. Otherwise an error will be thrown and the code below the `await` will not continue.

In your original code, you called `OnDelay.start(5000)` and it will run until the `await` line, to wait for that promise to resolve, and the control is back to the next line of `messageBox.add('finish waitting :)')` and it will be shown immediately.  It is not like a synchronous program where you can "sleep" for 5 seconds.  It is only possible if you do all that in an async function and you `await promise` that resolves in 5 seconds, and then do something, or by using a promise then resolves in 5 seconds, and set it to be `promise.then(doSomething)`.

For your original question:

> How to stop the execution of an asynchronous processing by an external command

There is a promise waiting to be resolved, and there is a `setTimeout` to resolve it 5 seconds later. So you can clear the timer, and reject the promise. If you don't reject (or resolve) it, the promise will just sit there forever. The `then` will not go on, or the lines after `await` will not go on either. If you reject the promise, you handle it by the second handler given to `then`, or by `catch`, or `finally`. If you use async function, then that `await` will throw an error and you can use `try-catch` to handle or ignore it.

### Using a promise and not async function:

Since you want the same action to be done even if the promise is rejected, you'd use `finally` instead of `then`.

```js
(function(messageBox) {
    const texBox = document.getElementById('message-box');
    messageBox.txt = txt => texBox.textContent = txt
    messageBox.add = txt => texBox.textContent += '\n' + txt
  }
  (window.messageBox = window.messageBox || {}));

function timer() {
  let timerID, rejectPromise;

  function start(nMS) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      timerID = setTimeout(_ => {
        timerID = undefined;
        resolve();
      }, nMS);
      rejectPromise = reject;
    });
  }
  
  function stop() {
    timerID && clearTimeout(timerID);
    timerID = undefined;
    rejectPromise();
  }

  return ({
    start,
    stop
  })
}

const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start'),
  btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort'),
  OnDelay = timer();
  
btStart.onclick = _ => {
  messageBox.txt('Start waitting 5 seconds...')
  OnDelay.start(5000).catch(err => {}).finally(_ => messageBox.add('finish waitting :)'));
}

btAbort.onclick = _ => {
  OnDelay.stop()
  messageBox.add('...abort !')
}
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightskyblue;
  width: 20em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>
<pre id="message-box">message...</pre>
```

Comment: your code doesn't show `finish wait:)` **from** `btStart` when I clicck on abort... :/

Comment: you mean even when "abort", it has to show "finish wait"?  If that's what you want, that's fine, I can change it... but usually if you "wait" and then you "abort", then the "wait" is aborted, and it should not finish!

Comment: yes, that's the point, I want the code arriving after `OnDelay.start(5000)` to always be able to be executed

Comment: @MisterJojo ok I have changed both methods to print out "finished" even if it is aborted.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at my question (+1). I study your answer, but it will take me a little time to assimilate it well

Answer (score 1):

I have added below simple code which may simulate your desired execution and will help to resolve your query.

```js
(() => {
  const messageBox = document.getElementById('message-box');       
  const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start');
  const btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort');
  const interval = 5000;
  
  let objTimeout = null;  
  btStart.onclick = () => {
    messageBox.textContent += `\n [-] start waiting ${interval} ms...`;
    objTimeout = setTimeout(()=>{
     messageBox.textContent += `\n [-] message  after ${interval} ms`;
    },interval)
  }
  btAbort.onclick = () => {  
    if(objTimeout){
     clearTimeout(objTimeout);
      messageBox.textContent += `\n [x] printing aborted`;
     messageBox.textContent += `\n [x] finish waiting`;
    }
  }

})();
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightskyblue;
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>
<pre id="message-box">waiting for message...</pre>
```

==================================================================
I have posted below snippet with promise.
You need to do the same promise only when you would like to synchronous code or to prevent the race condition or you would like to execute the statement line by line.

When we have no confidence that whether the promise will resolve or reject in this case we should use setTimeout and resolve or reject the promise.

I hope it puts some light on the issue and helps to resolve it.

```js
(() => {
  const messageBox = document.getElementById('message-box');
  const btStart = document.getElementById('bt-start');
  const btAbort = document.getElementById('bt-abort');
  const interval = 5000;
  let objTimeout = null;
  let objPromise = null;

  const appendMessage = (message) => {
    messageBox.textContent += message;
  }
  
  const addMessage = (message) => {
    messageBox.textContent = message;
  }

  const fnPromiseResolve = () => {
    console.log("promise resolved");
  };

  const fnPromiseReject = () => {
    clearTimeout(objTimeout);
    appendMessage(`\n [x] printing aborted`);
    appendMessage(`\n [x] finish waiting`);
    objTimeout = null;
  };

  btStart.onclick = () => {
    objTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
      Promise.resolve().then(() => {
        addMessage(`\n [-] start waitting ${interval} ms`);
      }).then(() => {
        appendMessage(`\n [-] message  after ${interval} ms`);
      }, interval).then(() => {
        appendMessage(`\n [-] printing finished`);
        objTimeout = null;
      });
    }, interval);
  }

  btAbort.onclick = () => {
    if (objTimeout !== null) {
      Promise.reject(new Error('printing aborted'))
        .then(fnPromiseResolve, fnPromiseReject);
    }
  }

})();
```

```css
#message-box {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid lightskyblue;
  width: 30em;
  height: 10em;
}
```

```html
<button id="bt-start">wait 5s</button>
<button id="bt-abort">abort</button>
<pre id="message-box">waiting for message...</pre>
```

Comment: I will update with promise as well. give me few moment.

Comment: @MisterJojo, when you use, promise it stops only when the process ends. It would not possible to abort the process in between. And your case is that you would like to abort the promise in between the process.

Comment: @MisterJojo Do you have any case of a race condition in your task and you need to execute statement line by line then you should use promise. The main purpose of promise to avoid asynchronous execution of the statement.

Comment: @MisterJojo it's ok. Feel free to check on your time.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look at my question (+1). I study your answer, but it will take me a little time to assimilate it well